# When trying to run the Audio/Video widget (based on the GoRTC library), i get a "...was interrupted while the page was loading" error

Tags: goinstant

[image: Here's a screen capture of the browser console]

I Googled the error and tried some of the suggestions, to no avail. This happened inside FireFox Aurora 29.0a2 on Windows, but i also got the same thing in Chrome on a Mac.

Any ideas as to what's causing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error will not affect the GoInstant service in any way. The error is logged by the browser for previous connections that are now disconnecting/interrupted on page refresh.

In other words, when you first connect in a fresh browser you will not see the error because you have no prior connections. Once you refresh, that first connection will be "interrupted" and you will create a new connection to GoInstant.